# Android 32 and above Error when accessing Coarse_Location and Fine_Location

Tags: android

I currently developing an Android application using Android studio. I discover that when i want to access Course_Location and Fine_Location, it kill the page for Android 30 and above.

[image]

This is how my Android Manifest looking like. For my Main_Activity Page I already create a code to check the permission. Is there any idea on how to solve it?

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); //<< this
        mDashboardActivity = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.backup_main);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            checkPermissions();
        else
           permissionOK();
    }



 private void checkPermissions() {
        String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String p : permissions) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, p) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
            }
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), 10);
        } else {
            permissionOK();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first ask for COARSE permission. And only after the user granted that ask for FINE.

Answer (score 0):

On **Android 12 (API level 31) or higher**, users can request that your app retrieve only approximate location information, even when your app requests the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` runtime permission.

To handle this potential user behavior, don't request the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission by itself. Instead, request both the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission and the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission in a single runtime request. If you try to request only `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, the system ignores the request on some releases of Android 12.

More details here:
[Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions)

Comment: OP is requesting both at the same time allready.